# Bootstrap 3.3.7 Modal Display Position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

My `bootstrap modal` displays center screen during development on Localhost, however, when deployed the modal displays to the right of screen with a large portion not visible.

The actual modal in my solution has some customization so I tested the problem in a 'clean solution' using the modal code provided on the bootstrap website and the problem is exactly the same.

Screenshots of the problem are below. I have not posted any code as the code is the standard example code from the bootstrap documentation. If the code is needed let me know.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is possibly some CSS being overwritten by something else, did you inspect the CSS to see if there are changes being made?

Comment: Hi Darren. I have inspected the css of both local and hosted versions and there is no difference that I can spot.

Comment: Inspect and look at class `.modal` for both and see if there are differences, specifically the `left` value